# Is it OK to use empty href on links with <base> tag

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I set the base tag as such:

```
<base href="http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/">
```

Then I would like to create a link to http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/ in relative path.

I tried:

```
<a href="">link</a>
```

and it works in Chrome, but is this method standard and supposed to work on every browser?

Comment: As far as I know, if you use such an empty link inside of a sub directory, you will be returned to the index page of that sub directory even when using a base tag. To always (i.e irrespective of which subfolder you are in) create a link to http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/ you should use <a href="/">link</a>, even when using a base tag - I think.

Comment: Not with the base tag, at least that's what I see when I try it. Go on http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/doc/, edit (Firebug or something) the "Home" link to an empty href and click on it. You will be redirected to the home page correctly.

Comment: To be clear I am trying to get rid of "index" links wich lead to duplicates URL with `/index` in the end (like `http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/index` for example)

Comment: You seem to be correct. I tested locally (using wamp server).  I specified `<base href='http://localhost/'>`.  I created a link with `href=''` in  `http://localhost/temp/index.php'.  When I click on link I am returned to http://localhost/index.php. When I change href='/' I am also returned to http://localhost/index.php.  In both FireFox and IE.

Comment: Strangely enough, this does not seem to work the same for form submission - I just tested this.  If you have a form with `action=''` and use a base tag, you are returned to the same location instead of the root folder.  But if you change `action='/'` and click submit, you are returned to the root folder.

Comment: You don't need a base tag to get rid of "index" links...?  Just use root-relative links like `href='/'` or `href='/home/'` or relative links like `href='../'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `href="./"` as suggested in Mike’s answer is better (easier to understand to anyone who reads the code), the answer to the question posed is that using an empty URL is standard and supposed to work on all browsers. According to [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), a relative URL with no characters (path-empty) is allowed, and by rules on relative URLs, it is resolved as the base URL.

This has nothing to do with folders or files; URLs are strings, and whether they get mapped to folders or files on a server is at the discretion of the server.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
<base href="http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/">

<a href="./">Home</a>
```