# Microsoft Edge bug, empty href and base tag

Tags: html, href, dry, microsoft-edge, base-tag

Microsoft's new browser Edge doesn't seem to accept empty hrefs like `<a href="">`. In all other browsers, this can be used to link to the `base` tag. Though in Edge this doesn't seem to be the case.

I found a solution to this problem by setting the href to `./` in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019985/is-it-ok-to-use-empty-href-on-links-with-base-tag).

But having to change this on many sites is quite a hassle. Are there any other alternatives that do not require to change all the href's themselves?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i test, everything is ok for me, i see no problem!!!

Comment: I asked some people to test the bug, they all had the same problem where the link just didn't seem to work. Maybe the problem is in my formatting of the base tag then. Could you post an example of your version?

Comment: Could you post a broken version, alec?

Comment: I'm using this base tag `<base href="https://www.example.com">` and a link formatted like this `<a href="">example</a>`.

Comment: This definitely seems to be a bug/oversight in Microsoft Edge. As RFC 3986 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986, Section 4 & 5) states, the base URI has to be prepended to any relative reference - and an empty path is also a relative reference (Section 4.2).

Comment: Thanks for your research. I'll try to submit some feedback about this to microsoft.

Comment: I hope this gets fixed eventually by Microsoft. This is causing a problem on a lot of websites.

Answer (score 0):

Use a utility function to rewrite the empty hrefs. For example:

```js
function rewrite_empty_hrefs()
  {
  var dom_parser = new DOMParser();

  var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  
  var old_html_dom = dom_parser.parseFromString(document.body.innerHTML,"text/html");

  var base_href = old_html_dom.querySelector("base").href;

  var old_xhtml_string = xml_serializer.serializeToString(old_html_dom);

  var new_xhtml_string = old_xhtml_string.replace(/(href=")(")/g, "$1"+base_href+"$2"); 

  document.body.innerHTML = new_xhtml_string;
  }

rewrite_empty_hrefs();
```

```html
<base href="http://www.example.com">
<a href="">example.com</a>
<a href="">example.org</a>
<a href="">example.net</a>
```

**References**

- [DOMParser and XMLSerializer in IE9 Beta – IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta/)